# Convert date to utc using the timezone passed from client(javascript)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, utc

I have a logic to show a message on the user screen for a particular time duration mentioned by the admin.

```
var time = DateTime.SpecifyKind(System.DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var date= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(time, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(System.TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id));
StringBuilder dispalyMessage = new StringBuilder("<marquee scrolldelay='90' behavior='scroll' scrollamount='1' direction='left'><b><ul>");
var bannerMessageIds = new HashSet<int>(db.CompanyBanners.Where(c => c.CompanyId == PortalUser.Current.CurrentCompanyId).Select(x => x.BannerMessageId));
List<BannerMessage> bannerMessages = db.BannerMessages.Where(p => bannerMessageIds.Contains(p.Id)  && (p.StartDate < date && p.EndDate > date) ).ToList();
```

Here the problem is I am converting the time to check using the server timezone.

Is there a way to pass the client timezone from javascript to c# and convert the date as per that time zone.

I mean something like this

```
var date= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(time, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("time zone id passed from client javascript"));
```

Comment: Your database should store time in UTC, and so you should compare against DateTime.UtcNow, without any timezone conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I think NO. but you can get the timezoneoffset in JavaScript like Below.

```
function myFunction() {
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

This should serve your purpose.

Comment: Yes. I know. But is there a way to get the client timezone on server side? I know its not a direct question.

Answer (score 0):

> Client-side

```
  Create a script that will be executed at every time the page loads.
    In the script check if the cookie that stores timezone offset exists.
    If the cookie not exists check whether the browser supports cookie.
    If the browser supports cookie create a new one and store the timezone offset.
    Reload the page if the cookie is created for the first time or expired.
    If the timezone cookie already exists check if the current timezone and the one stored in cookie are same. 
If they are different then overwrite with new timezone and reload the page.
```

> Server-side

```
    Read the cookie value on every request and store it in session.
    Create a utility method that converts the passed datetime in UTC to the client timezone by adjusting it with the offset read from session.
  If there is no value in session possibly the browser doesn’t supports cookie then convert the date-time to server timezone.
```

> [Look here for complete implantation and more hints](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/9/how_to_display_dates_and_times_in_clients_timezone)

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the datetimes in the database in UTC, you shouldn't care. So unless I've missed something (always possible :)), can you not just query on the value of DateTime.UtcNow, and not do any timezone conversion at this part?

e.g. 
User's timezone, it's 13:00.
Server's timezone, it's 10:00.
UTC time is 09:00.

When you store the times in the database, you convert the entered dates/times from the user's timezone to UTC (either in javascript or server-side), so a user-entered time of 13:00 gets stored in UTC as 09:00.

When the user then hits the page, you want to find all messages that should be shown "now". "Now" to the user is 13:00, but in UTC it's 09:00. So searching based on that UTC time should be all that's needed.